# Creating shapefiles using textfiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, vector, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile in QGIS which has polygons in it . There are several other attributes for each feature .

I want to add another attribute to each feature . The value for this attribute is available to me in a text file . How do i add this column programatically to the existing shapefile's attribute table .

It is not feasible to do it manually as i will have to change the value of that attribute quite often and the number of features are in thousands.

I am open to suggestions to use other GIS software if that fits my requirements.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the Tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that comes to mind is to use a join between your shapefile and the textfile. [Its described on this tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html).

If the attributes values change often, you could use a database backend for your data. QGIS works especially well with PostgreSQL-Postgis databases.

Comment: I will definitely try that